# Mapping route to a explicit path does not work

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am defining a resource as explained [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources):

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('phones', { path: '/nodes/extensions/phones' }, function () {
        this.route('new');
    });
```

But this is not working. Finding the `phones` performs a request to `/phones` instead of using the configured value `/nodes/extensions/phones`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you mean by 'finding the phones'? The data retrieval request to the backend?

Comment: Well, in ember terms listing the assets is call "finding"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` here is the path used in the browser address bar, e.g. a user would access "http://yoursite.com/#/nodes/extensions/phones" to see this page on your site.

If instead you want to configure the endpoint that the Ember app accesses to retrieve the json, e.g. "http://yoursite.com/api/nodes/extensions/phones" then that needs to be configured in your ember-data adapter or in your model's data retrieval functions.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do: configure the endpoint. I need to specify a different endpoint for each of my models, since my backend is not exactly structured the way ember expects it to be. How can I configure the endpoints on a model basis? I can not find any information about this. The closest I have found is http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_endpoint-path-customization, but this will configure the top-level namespace for all models. I need to configure it on a model by model basis.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure, but going by the first example under the link you provided, it seems like the path only determines what you type in the address bar while 'phones' determines the route that is addressed. so changing 'phones' to 'nodes.extensions.phones' could maybe help.