# Defining an API endpoint on a model-by-model basis

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

(This question is a continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15812438/647991))

I need to specify the API endpoints on a model by model basis. How can I do this? The closest I have come to this is the description of [namespace](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_endpoint-path-customization), but this applies to the top-level URL.

My problem is that my API structure is not the one that emberjs expects. For example, I have this two objects, with completely different API endpoints:

```
phones -> /api/nodes/extensions/phones
nodes  -> /api/nodes
```

How can I configure the endpoints for each model?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to set the `Model` url property, something like this:

```
App.Phone = DS.Model.extend({
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    number: DS.attr('string')
}).reopenClass({
    url: 'api/nodes/extensions/phones'
});

App.Node= DS.Model.extend({
    description: DS.attr('string')
}).reopenClass({
    url: 'api/nodes'
});
```

I haven't tried this with revision 12, so I can't guarantee it works.

Alternatively, you might want to look this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710296/add-extra-url-params-per-model-with-ember-js) which talks about a similar scenario, but using [adapter for a specific models](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#loading-data) introduced in revision 11.